# C++ double dispatch example

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

I got this code as an example of use of double dispatch, but I don't really understand one part of the code. creating the "abstract class" Printer, why I need to add:

```
virtual void print(PDFDoc *d)=0;
virtual void print(DocDoc *d)=0;
```

As I understand it, at run time  `p.print(docA);` will send me to `virtual void print(Document *d)` of myPrinter, then `d->printMe(this)` will send me to printMe of PDFDoc and then it will call at run time to `virtual void print(PDFDoc *d)` of my printer?

So why defining

```
virtual void print(PDFDoc *d)=0;
virtual void print(DocDoc *d)=0;
```

is necessary for the abstract class?

```
class Document{
public:
      //this is the accept function
      virtual void printMe(Printer *p)=0;
};

    class Printer{
    public:
    virtual void print(Document *d)=0;

     //the visitors
     virtual void print(PDFDoc *d)=0;
     virtual void print(DocDoc *d)=0;
     };

 class PDFDoc : public virtual Document{
 public:
     virtual void printMe(Printer *p){
         std::cout << "PDFDoc accepting a print call" << std::endl;
         p->print(this);
     }
 };

class DocDoc : public virtual Document{
public:
    virtual void printMe(Printer *p){
        std::cout << "DocDoc accepting a print call" << std::endl;
        p->print(this);
    }
};


class MyPrinter : public virtual Printer{
public:
    virtual void print(Document *d){
        std::cout << "dispatching function <print> called" << std::endl;
        d->printMe(this);
    }
    virtual void print(PDFDoc *d){
        std::cout << "printing a PDF doc" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void print(DocDoc *d){
        std::cout << "printing a Doc doc" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    MyPrinter p;
    Document *docA = new PDFDoc();
    Document *docB = new DocDoc(); 
    p.print(docA);
    p.print(docB);
    delete docA;
    delete docB;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `virtual void Printer::print(Document *d)=0;` should probably be renamed to `print_dispatch`. as text from `MyPrinter` document the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the argument to `printMe()` is the pointer to the abstract base class, `Printer`:

```
virtual void printMe(Printer *p){
```

And the purpose of the "double-dispatch" design pattern is to implement `print()` passing the appropriate derived `Document` class as a parameter.

Without the overloads for the derived `Document` classes, the only method in the base class is the one that takes the abstract `Document` base class:

```
     p->print(this);
```

And without the additional overloads, this just calls the same virtual method that takes the virtual `Document` base class as a parameter.

The sequence of events is:

1. The virtual base class `Printer` gets called with the parameter being the virtual document class `Document`.
2. The actual printer implementations use on the actual class that's derived from Document.
3. So, `Document`'s pure virtual `printMe()` method gets called, from `print()` that takes the `Document` pointer as a parameter.
4. The only parameter that `printMe()` takes is the virtual `Printer` base class pointer.
5. So, whatever `printMe()` calls, it can only call the methods defined in the virtual `Printer` base class.
6. Therefore, if the actual printer implementation needs to use the derived `Document` class, those methods have to be virtual methods in the `Printer` base class.
7. Those virtual methods don't really have to be `print()` overloads. They can be anything. It might be more clear, to some, to name them something different, like `printPDF()` and `printDoc`(). If you were to rewrite them, as such, it might be clearer what's going on.